# Get value from clicked parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="switchStatus btn-group" data-module="xxx">
          <a class="btn btn-primary">Active</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary">Inactive</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `data-module` content ?

Actually, my code looks like this but it doesn't work:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.switchStatus a', function() {
    var module = $(this).data('module');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: module attribute is on the parent..... not the anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`var module = $(this).parent().data('module');`

Comment: `.closest()` is almost always preferred to `.parent()` as it does not require specific hierarchical structure, making it easier to modify the DOM later on without having to rewrite all of your javascript selectors.

Comment: @mhodges, I agree. However in this case, the parent is just a wrapper div containing two hyperlink `a` tags, which shouldn't change in parts.

Comment: I agree with you, but developers should always aim to write as future-proof code as possible. There is no good reason (especially in this case) to not do so, either.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click handler callback function, the `this context` will be bound to the `<a>` element that was clicked. To get the parent, you can use the `.closest()` method with a selector. It could look like the following:

`$(this).closest("[data-module]").attr("data-module");`

Answer (score 1):

Use closest('.switchStatus').

> jQuery sets the scope of the callback function to the element which is
>   the subject of the callback

So I guess that means the elements in the on selector parameter (.switchStatus a in this case)

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.switchStatus a', function(event) {
    var module = $(this).closest('.switchStatus').data('module');
    console.log('My name is ' + module)
    event.stopPropagation() // always good to stop event bubbles after you have used them.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="switchStatus btn-group" data-module="Spartacus">
          <a class="btn btn-primary">Active</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary">Inactive</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, whitout the node 'a'

```
$('.container').on('click', '.switchStatus', function() {
    var module = $(this).data('module');
    alert(module);
});
```